Best approach for disputing a verbal contract for international online order?
I tried ordering an item online from a US seller for shipment to the UK. When switching from US Dollars to British Pounds on the seller's website, the figure went up instead of down, which is the opposite of what is expected due to currency exchange rates. For example, an item priced at $500 would be about £400 before taxes and shipping. I called their customer service, recording the call (if it matters, they are a "one party consent" state) and the agent I reached confirmed this was not the expected price. He voluntarily offered to adjust the charge if I placed an order online and called back.
This sounded odd so I waited a few weeks to see if the company would fix the website, then when I saw the item was on sale I called again (and again recording that call) when a different customer service agent also confirmed that they were happy to adjust the amount paid post-order and gave me a reference number to use if I ordered and called back.
I ordered at the unusually high price in British Pounds, called back and supplied the reference number, and you guessed it, suddenly no one could recall making any such offer and they refused to amend or cancel my  order. No response to emails to their main customer service address either.
I've initiated a chargeback with my UK bank, but I wonder if this is the best approach? I am troubled by the fact that this company has a good reputation and makes a fairly niche product, and yet would still try doing this to a customer. Do I have any other remedies available to me? My understanding is that verbal contracts are enforceable and with both parties having recorded the calls, and the company's customer service agents voluntarily offering to price correct after I ordered, I would hope to prevail.

Is it worth the trouble for you to handle a case across the ocean?

The elements of a contract are 1) an offer, 2) acceptance, 3) consideration (an exchange), and 4) an intention to create legal relations. You are right that there is no requirement for the contract to be written. As long as all of the above are met, the contract is enforceable.

If you receive legal advice (based on the above) that there was a contract and the company have breached their contractual obligations, then you may be able to sue them for breach of contract. However, as the above comment states, dealing with an overseas case won't be particularly convenient.

@littleadv "Is it worth the trouble for you to handle a case across the ocean?" Possibly not, but there is no chance I will allow a company to get away with doing this to me. There are a range of options available to customers who have been scammed, and with my question I'm exploring what those might include.

Money@se would probably be a better stack for that

A couple of suggestions (as your post is receiving close votes): 1) questions on this site should not be asking for legal advice. These questions should be de-personalised to be framed as hypotheticals. 2) based on my comments above, you should edit your post to explain why you believe you have all the elements of a valid contract (then it will be easier for answerers to tell you if you have a case).

For example: you mention two verbal offers, but as far as I can tell, you did not explicitly try to accept this offer until you made the third phone call (separate from the phone calls where the offers were made). If you accepted at any earlier point, it would be helpful to know

@FD_bfa No problem on the close votes, the comments here are helpful and I have a better understanding now. I did accept the first and second offers and will pursue a few different options. Thanks for the feedback.
